# Android Unit Tests Kotlin library Mockk crashes with strange exception

Tags: java, android, kotlin, unit-testing, mockk

Trying to launch any UT using mockk library I'm getting the following crash:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: getLogger(cls.java) must not be null
    at io.mockk.impl.log.Slf4jLogger.<init>(Slf4jLogger.kt:7)
    at io.mockk.impl.log.JvmLogging.slf4jOrJulLogging(JvmLogging.kt:10)
    at io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway.<clinit>(JvmMockKGateway.kt:165)
    ... 51 more
```

I've tried a lot of things already. This is just happens when mockk() method is invoked.
Tried to lower the SL4J dependency, didn't help.
My dependencies are:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.8.1'

testImplementation 'io.mockk:mockk:1.13.4'
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.